# TYPO3 v11 breadcrumb

Tags: typo3

I'm using TYPO3 v11. It has a self-written extension with one page for products. This page is in root tree two. At the same time, this plugin is used on pages at the fourth and fifth levels. How can I add page navigation-breadcrumb from TYPO3 to the page that displays a variable with different content generated by the plugin?

```
<div class="breadcrumbProd">
    <div><f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.breadcrumb" /></div>
    <div>{detail.title}</div>
</div>
```

```
lib.breadcrumb = HMENU
lib.breadcrumb {
  wrap = <ul class="breadcrumb">|</ul>
  special = rootline
  special.range = 1|-1
  // render the menu
  1 = TMENU
  1 {
    NO.wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>
    // render the current page without link and with additional classs
    CUR = 1
    CUR.doNotLinkIt = 1
    CUR.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="active">|</li>
  }
}
```

The standard method doesn't work

Comment: are you trying to show records with detail view located in one fixed page, from different pages with list views and expect a breadcrumb based on the page with the list? it seems you want to display the breadcrumb inside the plugin which is a bad idea as the breadcrumb does not belong to the detail view of a plugin.